# Is not researching before asking OK?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Many well-received questions in this site have very little evidence of researching. Just take the top voted question for an example:

> ## [How can I protect my eyesight when using computers?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/52/99)
>
> My job requires long periods of computer screen use. I have good eyesight (20/15) and don't wear glasses, but I definitely notice my eyes feeling fatigued at the end of the day. Sometimes when I'm short on sleep, I have trouble focusing or see slightly blurred vision.
>
> I want to protect my eyesight as much as possible. What are the best practices for doing so if you spend a lot of time staring at screens?

I'm not saying all questions are like that, but it doesn't show any research IMO. Or is listing symptoms enough to be considered as research? If we accept this manner, then do I need to feel guilty for not having research before asking?

From [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), the number one tip for a good question is:

> ## Search, and research
>
> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: I would argue that Health is a special case. It is more difficult to research without pre-existing knowledge. (All SO members know a bit about programming, that's why they are there. Users on Health have a different interest). The question you quoted is something I'd have closed as *too broad* or *opinion-based*, and wouldn't have worried about research. The feeling I get from most questions on Health is that they are either partly researched (i.e. I've heard but couldn't verify) or about self-diagnosis which you can't research.

Comment: You're right, he should have included something about what he's found so far.  Googling it brings a million links to info.  It would have been better if he explained he's seen differing advice and wanted to know best practices.  And it's kind of a borderline medical advice question.  It's asking best practices for looking at close screens -BUT- it gives a clinical scenario along with it.  The clinical scenario should have been stripped out, IMHO, before it was answered. Another challenge is that was a question from 2 years ago, when different people were active, so I don't know their mindset.